# Как настроить background для spinner

Tags: android

У меня есть два .png файла для `Spinner`. Один становится, когда `Spinner` не активен, а другой, когда он нажат. Вот сами файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот `background`, который я назначаю для `Spinner`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_default" />
</selector>
```

А вот, как я его назначаю:

```
spinner.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spinner_background));
```

В результате у меня выходит вот так >:-( :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В кастомной разметке для адаптера, который я подключаю к `Spinner`, у меня такая разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@drawable/item_spinner_background_one" />
```

Вот `item_spinner_background_one`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/light_gray" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Но ее `background` отвечает только за сам `TextView`, вот наглядный пример (я поставил для `background` у `TextView` красный цвет):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы иконки отображались корректно и черные линия отвечали за контент и растягивание, а не сами попадали на иконку.

Вот иконки кнопок — https://yadi.sk/d/oYYhj4uLk77ns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тормоз... Ошибка в том, что я поставил не то расширение. У меня было .png, а нужно было .9.png.

Comment: @norbornen, это же ответ.

Comment: @norbornen, это и есть ответ.